# External Webcam not working for Opencv and Python

Tags: python, opencv, webcam

I'm using Python cv2 module to use to run a program.

I'm able to access the inbuilt webcam but when I using the external webcam, it doesn't work.

I have used all codes like

```
VideoCapture(1) # or any other no.s like 0,1,2,3 etc etc.
```

I have even disabled the inbuilt webcam using device manager.

but nothing works. I'm using pythonxy. I have tried in command prompt also. It still doesn't work.

I get the following error

```
runfile('C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/Python Scripts/Circledetection.py',     wdir=r'C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/Python Scripts')
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn == 3 || scn == 4) in unknown function, file ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp, line 3402
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 540, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "C:/Users/Prashant/Documents/Python Scripts/Circledetection.py", line 27, in <module>
    prev_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: ..\..\..\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:3402: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4
```

Comment: the error just states, that your image was empty ( because the capture was not opened. )  try to install a proper driver for your external webcam.

Comment: i am able to use the webcam from win8 Camera app .. and when i check for updating drivers from device manager, it shows "Windows has determined that the driver software for your device is Up to date" .

Answer (score 2):

That assertion means that your image does not have 3 (RGB, BGR, etc) channels, or 4 channels (3 channels + alpha). This can be caused, obviously, by the image not existing at all.

While this might be because your camera isn't working, it's equally likely that your camera does not give usable frames for the first few read(), as it's still 'preparing' itself.

The easiest way to solve this, assuming you use something like
`retv, frame = cam.read()`
is to check `if frame:` or `if retv:`.

Have it skip over your processing if there's no image, and within a few frames you should have input that is readable.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned `VideoCapture(0)` to `VideoCapture(1)`.
"1" means external camera number.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1) 
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #print(height)
    #cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", crop_img)
    #gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the correct index? Using `Videocapture`you can also try to use `Videocapture(-1)`, since the external cam sometimes appears as the last element in the list of input. `Videocapture` also can return device names, so you could try to loop over the input devices index list and print their " friendly names", to make sure you are using the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV requires the following dependencies to work with the USB cameras. Install the dependencies from the following commands:

- libav video input/output development libraries

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev
  ```
- Video4Linux camera development libraries

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
  ```
- OpenGL development libraries (to allow creating graphical windows)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
  ```
- GTK development libraries (to allow creating graphical windows)

  ```
  sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it works for me.

OpenCV requires the following dependencies to work with the USB cameras. Install the dependencies from the following commands:

libav video input/output development libraries

sudo apt-get install libavformat-dev libavutil-dev libswscale-dev
Video4Linux camera development libraries

sudo apt-get install libv4l-dev
OpenGL development libraries (to allow creating graphical windows)

sudo apt-get install libglew-dev
GTK development libraries (to allow creating graphical windows)

sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install virtual environment:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then:

```
python -m virtualenv .
```

Then run your python program with this:

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

Try this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).